# Display values in Pareto chart using Chart.js 2.0.2

Tags: javascript, chart.js, pareto-chart

I have a Pareto chart (using Chart.js Version: 2.0.2) and i need to display values inside of the bars and under the line.

Any help will be very appreciated:

This is the code (hope that it is useful for somebody):

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = {
        labels: ["8","7","9","11","10"],
        datasets: [{
            type: "line",
            label: "Acumulado",
            borderColor: "#BA1E14",
            backgroundColor: "#BA1E14",
            pointBorderWidth: 5,
            fill: false,
            data: [34.04,57.45,76.60,89.36,100.00],
            yAxisID: 'y-axis-2'
        },{
            type: "bar",
            label: "Asistencia",
            borderColor: "#56B513",
            backgroundColor: "#56B513",
            data: [16,11,9,6,5],
            yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'
        },{
            type: "bar",
            label: "Solución",
            borderColor: "#000FAA",
            backgroundColor: "#000FAA",
            data: [16,11,9,6,5],
            yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'
        }]
    };

    var options = {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: "Estaciones"
                }
            }],

            yAxes: [{
                type: "linear",
                position: "left",
                id: "y-axis-1",
                stacked: true,
                ticks: {
                    suggestedMin: 0
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: "Minutos"
                }
            },{
                type: "linear",
                position: "right",
                id: "y-axis-2",
                ticks: {
                    suggestedMin: 0,
                    callback: function(value) {
                        return value + "%";
                    }
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: "Porcentaje"
                }
            }]
        }
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: data,
            options: options
        });
    };
</script>
```

Right now the chart looks like this:
[image]
And i need it to look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer i developed (only in the options object):

```
var options = {
    animation: {
        onComplete: function() {
            var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
            ctx.textAlign = "center";
            ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

            this.chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
                ctx.font = "20px Arial";
                switch (dataset.type) {
                    case "line":
                        ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
                        dataset.metaData.forEach(function(p) {
                            ctx.fillText(p._chart.config.data.datasets[p._datasetIndex].data[p._index], p._model.x, p._model.y - 20);
                        });
                        break;
                    case "bar":
                        ctx.fillStyle = "White";
                        dataset.metaData.forEach(function(p) {
                            ctx.fillText(p._chart.config.data.datasets[p._datasetIndex].data[p._index], p._model.x, p._model.y  + 20);
                        });
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
    }
...
};
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think since version 2.6.0 it's possible to Mix ChartTypes, like Bars and Lines

follow the [instructions](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/charts/mixed.html)

A short example is 2 DataSet, one is bar type and other line type:

```
const data = {
  labels: [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April'
  ],
  datasets: [{
    type: 'bar',
    label: 'Bar Dataset',
    data: [10, 20, 30, 40],
    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    label: 'Line Dataset',
    data: [50, 50, 50, 50],
    fill: false,
    borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)'
  }]
};
```

You just have to calculate the Pareto values and put on the Dataset Line Type