# Bar values in Chart.js 2.X - dataset.metadata undefined

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am quite new at Chart.js 2, so any help will be appreciated.

I'm trying to show values for each bar in the chart. As suggested in [Display values in Pareto chart using Chart.js 2.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927330/display-values-in-pareto-chart-using-chart-js-2-0-2) and other users I'm using this solution. However, this part throws an exception `TypeError: dataset.metaData is undefined`
:

```
dataset.metaData.forEach(function(p) {
   ctx.fillText(p._chart.config.data.datasets[p._datasetIndex].data[p._index], p._model.x, p._model.y  + 20);
});
```

I just want to show the value over the bar. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the below updated `onComplete`, your code should work with Chart.js v2.1

```
...
var options = {
    animation: {
        onComplete: function() {
            var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
            ctx.textAlign = "center";
            ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
            var chart = this;
            var datasets = this.config.data.datasets;

            datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                ctx.font = "20px Arial";
                switch (dataset.type) {
                    case "line":
                        ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
                        chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function (p, j) {
                            ctx.fillText(datasets[i].data[j], p._model.x, p._model.y - 20);
                        });
                        break;
                    case "bar":
                        ctx.fillStyle = "White";
                        chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function (p, j) {
                            ctx.fillText(datasets[i].data[j], p._model.x, p._model.y + 20);
                        });
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
    },
    ...
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/0j4g7kxy/

I've assumed you needed only the *bar*, but I have retained the code for *line* in the `onComplete`, so it should work for lines too. If you don't need either, just remove the related `case` from the `onComplete` code

Comment: Upgraded to 2.1, changed the code and it worked flawlessly. Thanks a lot for the help and for all your work.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to potatopeelings's answer,
using Chart.js v2.5, I had to adjust the following:

`switch (dataset.type)` to `switch ( chart.getDatasetMeta(i).type )`

Answer (score 1):

Works for me! **chart.js 2.5.0**

In addition to potatopeelings's and slashpm answers.

To handle **horizontalBar** you can add this case (change the padding "offsetY" to "offsetX")

```
case "horizontalBar":
    ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
    chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function (p, j) {
    ctx.fillText(datasets[i].data[j], p._model.x + 20, p._model.y);
  });
break;
```

Here is the full function

```
function chartValuesShow() { // show max values of the chart
  var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  var chart = this;
  var datasets = this.config.data.datasets;

  datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
    ctx.fontSize = "10px";
    switch (chart.getDatasetMeta(i).type) {
      case "line":
        ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
        chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function (p, j) {
          ctx.fillText(datasets[i].data[j], p._model.x, p._model.y - 20);
        });
        break;
      case "bar":
        ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
        chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function (p, j) {
          ctx.fillText(datasets[i].data[j], p._model.x, p._model.y + 20);
        });
        break;
      case "horizontalBar":
        ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
        chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function (p, j) {
          ctx.fillText(datasets[i].data[j], p._model.x + 20, p._model.y);
        });
        break;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have adapted it a little bit for horizontal Bars to show the sum of values instead of the stacked values. maybe someone can beautify the code a little bit but it works this way:

```
        onComplete: function() {
        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        var chart = this;
        var datasets = this.config.data.datasets;
        var sum=new Array();
        datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
            ctx.font = "10px Arial";

            switch ( chart.getDatasetMeta(i).type ) {
                case "line":
                    ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
                    chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function (p, j) {
                        ctx.fillText(datasets[i].data[j], p._model.x, p._model.y - 20);
                    });
                    break;
                case "bar":
                    ctx.fillStyle = "White";
                    chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function (p, j) {
                        ctx.fillText(datasets[i].data[j], p._model.x, p._model.y + 20);
                    });
                    break;
                case "horizontalBar":
                    ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
                    chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function (p, j) {
                    if (sum[j]== null) { sum[j] = 0; }
                    sum[j]=sum[j]+parseFloat(datasets[i].data[j]);
                    if (i==datasets.length-1) {ctx.fillText(sum[j], p._model.x+10, p._model.y);}

                    });

                    break;
            }
        });
    }
```